# How to use registry to refill a text box

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, registry

How can i refill a textbox with it's previous text after the program was stopped using registry.

I read multiple articles like:

[Stack OverFlow1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680705/how-to-save-class-object-in-registry)

[Stack OverFlow2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748500/howto-save-a-password-in-the-registry)

[Code Project1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19/Registry-Class)

[Code Project2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3389/Read-write-and-delete-from-registry-with-C)

So far i have nothing because nothing is working out, all i get are errors D:

```
     public string Read(string KeyName)
     { 
         RegistryKey rk = baseRegistryKey ;
         RegistryKey sk1 = rk.OpenSubKey(subKey);
         if ( sk1 == null )
              return null;
         else
         {
             try 
             {
                  return (string)sk1.GetValue(KeyName.ToUpper());
             }    
             catch (Exception ex)
             {

             }
         }
     }
```

says that baseRegistryKey and subKey don't exist. And it says that RegistryKey doesn't exist. How do i fix?

Comment: Please show us the code you're using (NOT links to the articles you've read) and tell us specifically what errors you are getting.

Comment: You have not defined the variables baseRegistryKey or subKey anywhere that I can tell.  So it makes sense that they don't exist.  Where is the code that was used to write data to the registry?  What were the registry keys used there?

Comment: @Gambit Ya someone already stated that as an answer. Thank you though, everything is fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same problem a couple of days ago, don't use those sights, they are all bad.

there are several things wrong with your code:

- baseRegistryKey and subKey need to be set to some sort of a parameter.
- if RegisterKey isn't working than you probably didn't do `using Microsoft.Win32`
- The code i used to solve this was:

  ```
  public WindowsConsoleForm1();
      try
      {
          InitializeComponent();
          textBox1.Text = Application.UserAppDataRegistry.GetValue("example").ToString();
      }
      catch { }
  ```
- and then where ever you have **ex:** `textbox1.text = Path.GetDirectoryName(saveFileDialoge1.FileName);`, under it you post `Application.UserAppDataRegistry.SetValue("example", textbox1.text);`